# Not update dataTable info

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables

I have a class list. As you can see in the first picture, there are different numbers of students in each class.

1st class -> 3

2nd class -> 0

3rd class -> 1

When I click on '(3)', I use the variable "sinif" as $scope.sinif for use in modal. I list $scope.sinif.ogrenciler in modal with ng-repeat. When I click (3), the list is correct. But when I turn off modal and click (0), the info is not updated. Likewise when I click (1). How can we solve this.

This is my first list. After clicking on the following modal opens.

[image: first]

Modal

[image: second]

This problem here. Look info
[image: My problem][image]

This is My modal.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade in" id="SinifOgrenci" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> {{this.sinif.sinifAdi}} - Öğrencileri </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table datatable-setups ng-if="sinif.ogrenciler" class="table table-bordered table-striped js-dataTable-full-pagination">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 5%;"></th>
                            <th class="text-center">Öğrenci Adı Soyadı</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Yaş</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Boy</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Cinsiyet</th>
                            <!--<th class="text-center">Aktif / Pasif</th>-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="ogrenci in sinif.ogrenciler">
                            <td class="hidden-xs">{{this.ogrenci.id}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{this.ogrenci.adSoyad}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{this.ogrenci.yas}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{this.ogrenci.boy}}</td>     
                            <td class="text-center">{{this.ogrenci.cinsiyet}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Kapat </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

My datatable directive

```
angular.module("app")
        .directive('datatableSetups', ['$timeout', '$rootScope',
            function ($timeout, $rootScope) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function (scope, element) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element.dataTable({
                                pagingType: "full_numbers",
                                columnDefs: [],
                                pageLength: 10,
                                lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]]
                            });
                        });

                    }
                };
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: dataTables is only able to update info if itself is responsible for drawing the table. but you are just rendering the content with `ng-repeat`. How should dataTables be aware of something had happen with your `$scope` variable?

Comment: yep, if clicked count, `ng-click="setSinif(sinif)"` call and `$scope.setSinif = function (sinif) {
                    $scope.sinif = sinif;
                };`

Comment: Have no idea what the above comment-code is supposed to solve :) Mixin a complex jQuery plugin as dataTables along with angular will only cause frustrations and weird behaviour, such as the result of race conditions.  Until you reinitialise the dataTable over and over **or** let the dataTable itself take care of rendering, you will face this problem in various ways. You simply cannot have the setup as above without facing issues. An alternative is to use angular-datatables, which I use use myself to solve all this predictable issues.